# Xamarin Forms Bottom Navigation Bar Not working for Ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I used the bottom bar navigation in my xamarin forms project and it working fine for android but for Ios this is background color and badge count feature is missing [image: ios preview]

2. [! Android Preview[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tq3v.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tq3v.png)

Comment: Could you show us some detailed code ?

Comment: Which plugin you are using?

Comment: You can find the entire project here
https://github.com/HoussemDellai/BottomBar-Xamarin-Forms